# call a function, after a dialog box gets dismissed

Tags: android

in my app, when the activity gets launched i am calling an AsynTask to load some details in the page. In between if the user clicks a button, an alert dialog builder used to appear. When the user clicks the Ok button i want the dialog to be dismissed and again i want to call the async task. how to do this.

i tried calling the function within the alert box before dismissing the dialog box it gets crashed.

and i tried calling the function after the `dialog.dismiss()` line, but then also the app get crashed.

how to do this, pls help me friends....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry made a mistake in my code.

in the do in Background process i am calling a  params value it is the reason for my error,

```
protected Void doInBackground(Bundle... params) 
{
    Bundle savedInstanceState = params[0];
        .....
        .....
}
```

after doing some changes in it, it is working good, sorry friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage("Connection timeout. Try again.")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                                 new Progress().execute("");                            
                            }                               
                        })
                    .show();
            }
```